# In .htaccess, how do you 301-redirect dynamic pages?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, dynamic

In .htaccess, how do you 301-redirect dynamic pages?

For example, what if I wanted a rule that made `www.domain.com/SomeFolder/theThing` redirect to `www.domain.com/theThing`?

I just want to remove the `/folder` and keep everything else. I already tried but no success.

EDIT:

I'm going to try be clearer. I have:

1. www.domain.com/SomeFolder/theThing
2. www.domain.com/SomeFolder/AnotherThing
3. www.domain.com/SomeFolder/AndOneMoreThing
4. ..and etc etc.

I want to remove this `SOMEFOLDER` because all those links were moved to index. But there's a lot of them and I was thinking about doing it automatically using dynamic redirect 301.

Comment: Must it be a 301 redirect or will a rename suffice?

Comment: I'm going to try be more clear. I have: www.domain.com/SomeFolder/theThing, www.domain.com/SomeFolder/AnotherThing www.domain.com/SomeFolder/AndOneMoreThing .. and etc etc. I wanna remove this SOMEFOLDER because all those links were moved to index. But it's a lot for them, I wanna do it automatically using dynamic redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do it.

**Using php:**

```
<?
 Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
 Header( "Location: http://www.new-url.com" );
?>
```

**Using htaccess**:

Create a .htaccess file with the below code, it will ensure that all your directories and pages of your old domain will get correctly redirected to your new domain.
The .htaccess file needs to be placed in the root directory of your old website (i.e the same directory where your index file is placed)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In addition to the redirect I would suggest that you contact every backlinking site to modify their backlink to point to your new website.

**Note:** This .htaccess method of redirection works ONLY on Linux servers having the Apache Mod-Rewrite moduled enabled.

Refer [this](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php/) for more methods

Comment: This won't help me in my case. I have a lot of links with /SomeFolder on it. I need an dynamic redirect. Not to redirect all of them to one page.

Comment: I'm going to try be more clear. I have www.domain.com/SomeFolder/theThing, www.domain.com/SomeFolder/AnotherThing www.domain.com/SomeFolder/AndOneMoreThing .. and etc etc. I wanna remove this SOMEFOLDER because all those links were moved to index. But it's a lot for them, I wanna do it automatically using dynamic redirect.